# How to load a QML plugin like a dependency for another QML plugin?

Tags: qt, plugins, qml, libs

I have 2 QML Plugins: icL.Look and icL.Editor, the second depend by the first. If I exclude the dependency all are working OK. But I need it. So when I run the app I get the next error

```
qrc:/windows/start-window.qml:5 plugin cannot be loaded for module
"icL.Editor": unable to load library /path/libicLeditorPlugin.so: 
(/path/libicLeditorPlugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3icL4look5Chars5clineE)
21:52:20: The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

icL.look.Chars.cline is a static field.

Do you have some idea?

Comment: check [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/79711/qml-plugin-link-to-c-library/2) maybe it can guide you.

Comment: There is not a solution for me, when a QML pugin depends by a lib there is not a problem, but the QML plugin depends by other QML plugin.

Comment: I think you need to set QML_IMPORT_PATH properly, either through an environment variable or in main.cpp: [Qt Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html#qml-import-path)